# How to bind the query string into model when controller is called in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, binding, asp.net-core, query-string

**Encodeurl**

> http://localhost:42934/PasswordReset?EmailID%3DbDMfrcUtXsDRV5hB4elj1OssF4CTu2W%2BV3A7bxKrark%3D%26code%3DNnm4trdRwduklESeDZKS8hnPJblhyS%2BvHrnuUdhzAzcByydom9HzDu5j7yMS4Ppl%26ID%3DVzdaeGt89k1m6hA%2BVwL%2BfA%3D%3D%26date%3DgtCLDxNwlGJk2eh1DHIW8eAlf3a8ZXUfJuLrAI2KT%2BI%3D

**Model**

```
 public class ResetPassword
    {
        [FromQuery(Name = "ID")]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [FromQuery(Name = "EmailID")]
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public DateTime RequestOn { get; set; }
        [FromQuery(Name = "Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [FromQuery(Name = "ResetCode")]
        public Guid ResetCode { get; set; }
        [FromQuery(Name = "Code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }`
```

I made two methods

**Not API**

```
[Route("PasswordReset")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Password([FromQuery]ResetPassword objResetPassword)
{
   // logic
}

[Route("PasswordReset")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Password(string EmailID,string ID,string Code,string Date)
{
   // logic
}
```

**Problem**

I am getting null.

Comment: have you set `ResetPassword` model in your view?

Comment: yes i set the [Route("ResetPassword")] [HttpGet] also

Comment: @Anil based on the example URL the query string is double encoded which is causing issues.I advise reviewing what ever is generating that URL.  Also both this API methods are the same. Just use one or you may get route conflicts